# SQL to LINQ issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I am working on a composite ranking website. I am trying to query the most recent ranking and the previous ranking side by side.
This query works great in SSMS, but I am unable to make this work in my C# code:

```
SELECT r.Name, l.RankValue AS currentValue, l.RankDT as CurrentDT, p.RankValue AS prevVal, p.RankDT AS prevDate
FROM RankLookupTB L 
JOIN RankingsTB R ON L.RankID = R.RankID
FULL JOIN (SELECT rankid, rankvalue, RankDT FROM RankLookupTB WHERE Obselete = 1 and TeamID = 356) AS P ON l.RankID = p.RankID  
WHERE l.TeamID = 356 and Obselete = 0
ORDER BY r.Name
```

Here is what I have in my Program:

```
    var ranks = from r in _context.RankLookupTbs
                where r.TeamId == id && r.Obselete == false
                join s in _context.RankingsTbs on r.RankId equals s.RankId
                join t in _context.RankLookupTbs on new { id = r.RankId, obsolete = r.Obselete } equals new { id = t.RankId, obsolete = true }
                select new { Name = s.Name, CurrentValue = r.RankValue, CurrentDT = r.RankDt, PastValue = t.RankValue, PastDT = t.RankDt };
```

I am sure that I am not far away from the answer. The join seems to be the problem because I am getting everything in the result set.

Lastly, I downloaded LINQPad, but it is not giving me anything at all.

Thanks for all insights

Comment: We can not solve a problem that does not exists. You did not mention what the problem is? Unless you provide the expected result.

Comment: EF, Linq To SQL, do not support `FULL JOIN`. It needs emulation via `Concat`.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Why doesn't your `join t` match your SQL query?

Comment: What ORM is in use here?